# Using ArcGIS JavaScript to display LAS point cloud data using Azure instead of ArcGIS server

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, azure

I have LAS point cloud data that I want to visualize in ArcGIS API for JavaScript, but from my understanding of the documentation, [one will need to host their LAS data on ArcGIS server for it to work](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-PointCloudLayer.html).

For displaying GeoJSON data, I have been hosting it on Azure to deliver it, and that is what I want to do with my LAS data as well. I want to find a way or service on Azure to deliver the LAS data for my web app.

From this [other GIS stack exchange question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13671/how-to-display-dynamic-raster-lidar-data-on-a-web-map), I see that GeoServer is a potential open source alternative for delivering spatial information, and it looks like there is an [Azure app as well for it](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en/marketplace/apps/apps-4-rent.geoserver-windows-server-2016?tab=Overview), but I could not find much on how one would be able to deliver LAS data through GeoServer.

To put my question succinctly: Is there an alternative to ArcGIS Server (like GeoServer) that I can host on Azure that can fulfil the back-end implementation of delivering LAS point cloud data for ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Comment: How big is your point cloud (file size)? Is it small enough be downloaded as a file by the application?

Comment: The point cloud files would total up to be ~15-30 GB total so I will need some type of server for sure. I will add that I was able to set up and use [Potree](https://github.com/potree/potree) to view individual point clouds, but I am hoping to be able to view all of the ~30 point clouds in one 3D interface like the first link in my question. Potree also looks like it [could overlay point clouds over a map](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Point-cloud-with-map-overlay-The-map-shows-the-extent-of-the-point-cloud-the-position_fig27_309358171), but only a single one.